# Why I'm getting a list instead of a vector?

Tags: vector, clojure, functional-programming, lisp

So, I'm trying to transform each element of a vector x,in this way: x[i]--> 1-(1/x[i])

```
(defn change[x]
  (fn [i]
    (assoc x i (- 1 (/ 1 (get x i))))
    )
  (range 0 (* (count x) 1))
  )
```

I'm using assoc to replace each element of the vector, I'm supposed to get a vector with the changes, but instead I'm getting a list.

For example
user> (change [21 32 23 34])

(0 1 2 3)

But I should get a vector :v

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code for the function you provided doesn't use the local anonymous function, and can be refactored greatly.

This is your original function with comments.

```
(defn change[x]

  ;; start unused anonymous
  (fn [i]
    (assoc x i (- 1 (/ 1 (get x i)))))
  ;; end unused anonymous

  ;; start/end gen list of ints
  (range 0 (* (count x) 1)))
```

This is probably what you mean

```
(defn change [coll]
  (mapv #(- 1 (/ 1 %)) coll))
```

And this is the output

```
user>  (change [21 32 23 34])
;=> [20/21 31/32 22/23 33/34]
```

Comment: You can abbreviate `(/ 1 %)` to `(/ %)`.

Answer (score 1):

**What your code does**

Your original code (reformatted)

```
(defn change [x]
  (fn [i] (assoc x i (- 1 (/ 1 (get x i)))))
  (range 0 (* (count x) 1)))
```

- evaluates and discards a function value then
- returns the `range`.

So you can omit the `fn` form and reduce it to

```
(defn change [x]
  (range 0 (* (count x) 1)))
```

which in turn reduces to

```
(defn change [x]
  (range (count x)))
```

So, for example,

```
(change [:whatever :I :choose :to :put :here])
;(0 1 2 3 4 5)
```